# Vim statusline separation (%=) with Unicode characters

Tags: vim, unicode

When I set `fillchars=stl:x statusline=a%=b`, I see the following statusline:

```
axxxxxb
```

When I set `fillchars=stl:· statusline=a%=b` (· = middle dot, U+00B7), the status line becomes:

```
a-----b
```

The same happens with Unicode box drawing characters (they become `-`).

I would have expected:

```
a·····b
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

If I don't set `statusline` to anything, then the default `statusline` draws the Unicode character correctly, something like:

```
~/.vimrc·····1,1·····Top
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Vim [does not currently support multi-byte fill characters](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.1.2203/src/buffer.c#L3971) in custom status lines (version 8.1.2203):

```c
/* Can't handle a multi-byte fill character yet. */
else if (mb_char2len(fillchar) > 1)
    fillchar = '-';
```

To work around the issue, I created a function that draws the line instead:

```
function StatusLine()
    let left = 'a'
    let right = 'b'

    let spacer_width = winwidth(0) - len(left) - len(right)
    let spacer = repeat('·', spacer_width)

    return left . spacer . right
endfunction

set statusline=%{StatusLine()}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not supported.

Quote from `:h 'fcs'`:

> for "stl" and "stlnc" only single-byte values are supported.

Comment: It's interesting that `stl` and `stlnc` do work with multiple bytes, but only if they're used inside the standard status line. If I try to use them in a custom status line, then they don't work anymore. Looking at the source code, I see that they are indeed handled correctly in the standard status line, and not handled in the custom one.